# Deleting a Post from a Stream

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, peewee

I am new to creating web applications, and I decided to start out by learning Flask. I am making a Social Network as a side-project to practice and learn some basic skills.

So far, I have been able to build a "Stream" that users can post to, kind of like Twitter. **I have been struggling to find a way to allow users to Delete posts.** I am using a SQLite database with the Peewee library. Here is what I have tried:

```
@app.route('/delete_post/<int:post_id>')
@login_required
def delete_post(post_id):
    delete = models.Post.select().where(models.Post.id == post_id)
    try:
        models.DATABASE.delete(delete)
    except models.DoesNotExist:
        abort(404)
    else:
        flash("This post has successfully been deleted.", "success")
    return redirect(url_for('stream', stream = stream))
```

Also, here is how a Post is created:

```
class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model= User,
        related_name='posts'
    )
    content = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-timestamp',)
```

Finally, there is the template where the delete_post method would be called when the use selects "Delete"

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in stream %}
    <article>
        <h2>
            <a href="{{ url_for('stream', username=post.user.username) }}">{{ post.user.username }}</a>
        </h2>
        <i class="clock"></i>
        <time>
        {{ post.timestamp.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M") }}
        </time>
        <a href="{{ url_for('view_post', post_id=post.id) }}" class="view">View</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('delete_post', post_id=post.id) }}" class="view" >| Delete</a>

        <div class="post">
            {{ post.content }}
        </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**How do I go about deleting a post?** When I try my solution I get: `AttributeError: 'SqliteDatabase' object has no attribute 'delete'`
I know this question is pretty long-winded, but any help would be much appreciated and would help me a lot in future projects. Let me know if I need to clarify anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the actual question?

Comment: I want to know how to go about deleting a post

Comment: My delete post_method does not work. When i try it I get: AttributeError: 'SqliteDatabase' object has no attribute 'delete'

Comment: What database library are you using? That’s where you should be looking at for how to delete something from the database. This has nothing to do with Flask or anything you talked about. This is only “How do I delete an object from the database using library X” where you didn’t tell us what X is.

Comment: At a guess, once you've got the Post object (which you call `delete`) do you just call a `delete` method on it? `delete.delete()`?

Comment: I am using an SQLite database with the Peewee library. I have tried calling a delete method on it but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete:

```
def delete_post(post_id):
    try:
        post = models.Post.select().where(models.Post.id == post_id).get()
    except models.Post.DoesNotExist:
        abort(404)

    post.delete_instance()
    flash("This post has successfully been deleted.", "success")
    return redirect(url_for('stream', stream = stream))
```

Alternatively, you can write:

```
def delete_post(post_id):
    post = models.Post.delete().where(models.Post.id == post_id).execute()
    flash("This post has successfully been deleted.", "success")
    return redirect(url_for('stream', stream = stream))
```

---

Edit: I also just want to point you to the docs, which cover all sorts of topics... http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#deleting-records